# Remove dulpicate rows from table in faster way

Tags: mysql

What is the best way to remove the dulpicate rows from a large table(500000+ rows).
I had a code it works well but it is not fast enough.
Here is a code.

```
DELETE foo
FROM foo
  INNER JOIN (SELECT
        link,
        MIN(id) AS MinId
          FROM foo
          GROUP BY link) b
    ON foo.link = b.link
      AND foo.id != b.MinId
```

Please tell me anyother way which is faster than this code.
Thanks.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query:

```
DELETE f
FROM foo f
WHERE (SELECT MIN(f1.id) 
       FROM (SELECT * FROM foo) f1
       WHERE f1.link = f.link) != f.id
```

Query to remove duplicate records which between in id=50 to id=100:

```
DELETE f
FROM foo f
WHERE (SELECT MIN(f1.id) 
       FROM (SELECT * FROM foo) f1
       WHERE f1.link = f.link) != f.id
AND f.id >= 50
AND f.id <= 100
```

Comment: How can I use this code to remove dulpicate rows which between in id=50 to id=100

Comment: I updatet answer, just testit if my query will work at all... because when there column inside subquery and outside, I'm not sure :)

Comment: Here is some problem in your code `You can't specify target table 'f' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: ok,I can change ur code like that. `DELETE f
FROM foo f
WHERE (SELECT MIN(f1.id) 
       FROM (SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id >=50 && id<=100) f1
       WHERE f1.link = f.link) != f.id
AND f.id >= 50
AND f.id <= 100` because my all dulpicte result in series.

Answer (score 2):

I would try this:

```
DELETE foo1
FROM foo foo1 INNER JOIN foo foo2
     ON foo1.link = foo2.link AND foo1.id>foo2.id
```

This will keep only the link with the minimum id.

Answer (score 1):

delete 
from [table] 
where rowid not in (select min(rowid) 
from [table] 
group by [primary key columns])

It will help in removing the duplicacy from table based on rowids.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DELETE foo
FROM foo
  INNER JOIN (SELECT
                link,
                MIN(id) AS MinId
          FROM foo
          GROUP BY link) b
    ON foo.link = b.link
WHERE foo.id <> b.MinId
```

Comment: it is also slow.How many time take it to complete if rows are approximately 1,00,000.Any idea???

Comment: Have you checked @fthiella 's answer. it seems batter. Try that one

Answer (score 0):

Short way: add constraint

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `foo` ADD UNIQUE `link` (`link`);
DROP INDEX `link` ON `foo`; -- to restore table state
```

But i think better to create new table with constraint

```
CREATE  TABLE `temp` LIKE `foo`;
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `temp` ADD UNIQUE `link` (`link`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `temp` SELECT * FROM `foo`;
RENAME TABLE `foo` TO `old_foo`, `temp` TO `foo`;
DROP TABLE `old_foo`;
DROP INDEX `link` ON `foo`; -- to restore table state
```

Did not test it.

P.S. Do not forget to lock table

P.P.S. Table cannot be locked. Anyway you must stop writing to that table before manipulations.

Comment: All the questions are good.Thanks for help.I realize that my computer is too slow to perfom this task.Now I am going to make a php code for that.Anyways THANKS For all.

Comment: @user2280065, with PHP it would not be faster. Did you try second solution?